# missed data received using Serial comport 411f delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, tcomport

I have a Delphi 7 code that receives sensor values from an DSP TMS32F28069. The value received by Delphi is Hex file data. For example I send data:

> F1;01;01;07;00;00;0A;00;00;00;00;F7

from DSP.

I use Comport 411f and actually when I use windows 10 64 bit english version everything is fine. But when I use windows chinese 64 bit, the data that received sometimes fine sometimes change. I have  try on several notebook using windows 7 64 bit chinese version, and it has the same problem. The received files on windows 7 64 bit chinese version showing:

> F1;01;01;01;00;00;00;F7;00;00;F7;00.or F1;01;07;01;00;0A;00;00;F7;F7;00;00

and always change.This is the code I wrote in Delphi 7:

```
procedure TForm1.ComPort1RxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var
p:integer;
r:array[1..12]of integer;
h:array[1..12]of String;
 begin
   comport1.Open;
  for p:=1 to 12 do
   begin
     comport1.Read(r[p],1);
     h[p]:= IntToHex((r[p]),2);
     sMemo3.Text:=   h[1]+';'+h[2]+';'+h[3]+';'+h[4]+';'+h[5]+';'+h[6]+';'+h[7]+';'+h[8]+';'+h[9]+';'+h[10]+';'+h[11]+';'+h[12];//Show data Receive on Memo4//
    end;
end;
```

Please give me any suggestion why this happened on windows 7 64 bit chinese version? because when I use windows 7 64 bit english version, it was also work fine.

Thank you

Comment: The `ComPort1RxChar` has a `count` input. This is the number of bytes received. You have to use that to fill a buffer that is global in scope, and once all bytes are received, you should interpret the complete message.

Comment: Do you have any example code? i would like to try it. Thank you.

Comment: You are also updating the memo inside the loop, which is a bit pointless. Update it once, when the message is complete.

Comment: okay, Thank you LU RD, it's good suggestion

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `comport1.Open` - it is undoubtedly opened if RxChar event occurs
2. Local integer array is filled with some crap.  `comport1.Read(r[p],1);` fills only one byte. So use byte array
3. You output full data array after every byte - it is strange method.
4. When event fires, port buffer contains `Count` bytes - so read real number of bytes. Better approach - accumulate received info in global array (or `ansistring`) and treat it when 12 bytes are received.

---

```
Buffer: AnsiString;
...

procedure TForm1.ComPort1RxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
var
  sa: AnsiString;
  ByteBuf: array[1..12] of Byte;
begin
   SetLength(sa, Count);
   comport1.Read(sa[1], Count);
   Buffer := Buffer + sa;
   while Length(Buffer) >= 12 do begin
      Move(Buffer[1], ByteBuf, 12); 
      TreatData(ByteBuf);
      Delete(Buffer, 1, 12);
   end;
 end;

 procedure TreatData(bb: array of Byte);
 //treat and output here
```

Comment: Hi Mbo, Could you also post the TreatData Function, I would like to try it.
Sorry Since I am beginner. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mbo, Ijust implement your code, and its work right now.
Thank you So Much for your help.